# Basic Bash backup script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm still learning how to program in bash and for practice i'm trying to do a "backup script" (quotes because I know this isn't a proper backup) here is the code:

```
#|/bin/bash

sudo mkdir /home/lucas/bkp
echo "Type the path for the directory you want do save"
read directory

if  [-d $directory]; then
    sudo cp -R $directory /home/lucas/bkp/

else 
    echo "Path not found"

fi
```

But I get an error saying the path saved on variable does not exists and doing the same commands by "hand", directly on the shell everything is fine. Here is the error:

```
lucas@lucas-Linux:~$ sudo sh ./ex.sh 
Type the path for the directory you want do save
/home/lucas/git/
./ex.sh: 7: ./ex.sh: [-d: not found
Path not found
```

Comment: You're missing space after `[`, correct is `[ -d $directory ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put spaces in your condition, like this :

```
if [ -d $directory ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the silly mistake haha. But anyway good to learn that. Thanks again